# CMS Made Simple: lost permission to access admin panel

Tags: php, mysql, http-status-code-403, cmsmadesimple

I'm a bit amateur (and absolutely new at CMS MS)  so it may be a little bit silly question, but I can't find answer anywhere..

I had took over an old page to renew it. So I was trying to update an old CMSMS version to new one manually. I had backed up all files of public_html directory (and deleted after back up) and backed up mySQL (but I didn't deleted it). And after I deleted all the files I remembered that I had forgotten to create page theme back ups, so I tried to recover an old page.

Things I did to recover it:

-restored old files of public_html

-changed password of old mySQL database and changed it in configuration file.

Webpage is working perfectly now, but I can't access an admin panel.
I got this message when I try to access it:

*403 Forbidenn
You don't have permission to access /admin/ on this server.*

Thanks for a help!

Answer (score 0):

If you are a user and have an email associated with your account you can use the Forgot your password? link.

If you don't have an email associated with that account and have access to the DB look at the users table for that user and edit it, in email box add email address, save, now you can use the forgot password link to get a reset email with a link to reset password.

I've found this easier than trying to change the password in the DB unless you are comfortable MySQL queries.